# MS Project 2013 VSTO Exception code: 0xc00000fd

Tags: vsto, ms-project

I wrote a VSTO application that runs perfectly fine in **Windows 7**. However, when running it on **Windows 8**, it will occasionally throw this error. I tried searching on the internet, but could not find anything.

```
Faulting application name: winproj.exe, version: 15.0.4517.1005, time stamp: 0x51b961d1
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0c047de0
Faulting process id: 0xc70
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce8964a6e2b407
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\winproj.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: f71ab2f7-f557-11e2-be7c-001f2900a8e5
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```